# Need help identifying opportunities for improvement in table config and query design

Tags: postgresql, performance, partitioning, index-tuning, postgresql-11

I am working on a project with a fairly large data set. We require arbitrary aggregates on this dataset, these are generated at request time from a user. Here is a basic description of our current setup in PostgresQL v11 (yes we know it is EOL, upgrading is on the map for next quarter)

Basic table structure is thus:

```
create table if not exists sales
(
    category_a  smallint,    -- sequential integer values from 0 - 10000
    category_b  varchar(3),  -- 3-digit ids (all numeric, padded with zeros)
    product     varchar(14), -- essentially random 14 character identifiers
    location_id varchar(5),  -- location id, 5-digit number (left padded with zeros)
    units       int,         -- value of interest
    sales       float,       -- second value of interest
    primary key (category_a, category_b, product, location_id)
) partition by range (category_a);
```

We currently partition by `A` because these rotate out after about 200 values, and are dropped from the dataset. `A` partitions are further sub-partitioned by `B`. Each of these `A_B` partitions contain about 50-70 million rows.

The values for `B` are non-sequential and have gaps.

There are many different values of product, about a million.

`location_id`, there are about 50-100 locations per category `B`, each with most of the products in them.

An example query looks like this:

```
select category_a, category_b, product, sum(units), sum(sales)
from sales
where category_a between 1 and 100
  and sales.category_b in ('001', '010', '018', '019', '024')
  and product in ('00000000000147', '00000000000900', '00000000000140', '00000000009999')
group by category_a, category_b, product;
```

The explain for this query indicates we hit a full sequential scan for every partition in the dataset. These seems odd since we have the unique index with the left three values being the three in the where and group clauses. I don't understand why this doesn't use the index.

Here is a query that will load example data into the table:

```
insert into sales
    (category_a, category_b, product, location_id, units, sales)
select cat_a,
       lpad(cat_b::varchar, 3, '0'),
       lpad(product::varchar, 14, '0'),
       lpad(location_id::varchar, 5, '0'),
       (random() * 10000)::int,
       (random() * 100000)::int
from generate_series(1, 50) cat_a
         cross join generate_series(1, 25) cat_b
         cross join generate_series(1, 10) location_id
         cross join generate_series(1, 5000) product;
```

The explain for that query is very long, but I can provide it if we think it will help.

These queries can be extremely slow (minutes, sometimes more than 10). More than happy to provide additional details, but this is the essential information (as I see it anyhow).

Are there changes we can/should make to our table or query that would increase the performance of this query?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: This [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Ct3Qmcay) will build your example test set with partitions, you might consider putting it in the question for convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [pastebin code](https://pastebin.com/Ct3Qmcay) to build test data.

Using postgres 16.1.

A btree index works like a phonebook, which I will use as an example. Entries are ordered by (last_name,first_name). Thus queries like this one:

```
last_name=constant AND first_name BETWEEN first AND last
```

...result in one seek to (last_name=constant, first_name=first) then scanning the index row in order until hitting (last_name=constant, first_name=last). This is fast.

Unfortunately, for queries like:

```
WHERE last_name BETWEEN ... AND first_name BETWEEN ....
```

it is more complicated and requires a different method: scan the index to find all the last_names that satisfy the condition, then for each, do what is described in the previous paragraph. Unfortunately this method is not currently implemented in postgres. So we have to give it a bit of manual help.

```
select category_a, category_b, product, sum(units), sum(sales)
from sales
where category_a between 1 and 100
  and sales.category_b in ('001', '010', '018', '019', '024')
  and product in ('00000000000147', '00000000000900', '00000000000140', '00000000009999')
group by category_a, category_b, product;
```

The original query takes 4300 ms.

Your example data only populates the table with category_a between 1 and 50 so the condition on category_a in the query is redundant, but I assume it is not redundant in the real query. Anyway, because category_a is a partition key, postgres will only read the partitions which are relevant to the query, so this part is already optimized.

> We currently partition by A because these rotate out after about 200 values, and are dropped from the dataset. A partitions are further sub-partitioned by B. Each of these A_B partitions contain about 50-70 million rows.

It is not clear whether you want to partition by A or A,B. I will assume you only partition by A since that's what's in the question.

Now as Laurenz Albe said your primary key index is not adequate for this query. You would need this one:

```
CREATE INDEX ON sales( category_b, product );
```

If you partitioned by A,B and not A, then you would only need an index on (product) because category_b would be handled at the partition level.

With this index, the above query does one index scan completes in 4ms, which is 1000 times faster. Just quoting a part of the EXPLAIN, there's one of these per partition:

```
 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on sales_a001 sales_1  (cost=90.60..799.11 rows=197 width=33) (actual time=0.468..0.596 rows=150 loops=1)
       Recheck Cond: (((category_b)::text = ANY ('{001,010,018,019,024}'::text[])) AND ((product)::text = ANY ('{00000000000147,00000000000900,00000000000140,00000000009999}'::text[])))
       Filter: ((category_a >= 1) AND (category_a <= 10))
       Heap Blocks: exact=9
       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on sales_a001_category_b_product_idx  (cost=0.00..90.55 rows=197 width=0) (actual time=0.447..0.447 rows=150 loops=1)
             Index Cond: (((category_b)::text = ANY ('{001,010,018,019,024}'::text[])) AND ((product)::text = ANY ('{00000000000147,00000000000900,00000000000140,00000000009999}'::text[])))
```

This is great, but you need an extra index, which is going to be pretty large. Can we do it without the index? Yes, by cheating a little bit. So, first, I drop the index created above, and:

```
select category_a, category_b, product, sum(units), sum(sales)
from sales
where category_a = 1
  and sales.category_b in ('001', '010', '018', '019', '024')
  and product in ('00000000000147', '00000000000900', '00000000000140', '00000000009999')
group by category_a, category_b, product;
```

If we use a constant category_a = 1 then postgres is able to use an index scan.

What it really does is take the two lists of category_b and product, iterate through them both to enumerate all the combinations, and do an index search for each combination. Still much faster than a seq scan.

This also works with:

```
select category_a, category_b, product, sum(units), sum(sales)
from sales
where category_a IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100)
  and sales.category_b in ('001', '010', '018', '019', '024')
  and product in ('00000000000147', '00000000000900', '00000000000140', '00000000009999')
group by category_a, category_b, product;
```

By replacing the range with a set of known values, it is able to use an index scan. However, the number of combinations to enumerate is quite large. Postgres does not understand that it can skip all the category_a values that do not exist in a partition, so it runs this search on each partition:

```
->  Index Scan using sales_a002_pkey on sales_a002 sales_2  (cost=0.43..8308.58 rows=202 width=33) (actual time=0.035..1.421 rows=150 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((category_a = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100}'::integer[])) AND ((category_b)::text = ANY ('{001,010,018,019,024}'::text[])) AND ((product)::text = ANY ('{00000000000147,00000000000900,00000000000140,00000000009999}'::text[])))
```

So the query is much faster (175ms) than the all-seq-scan query (4300ms), but it is also much slower than with the index on (category_b,product) (4ms). Still, an interesting middle ground if this is an occasional query and you don't want to lug around a huge index just for this one.

Now, of course there is the option to cheat even more :

```
select category_a, category_b, product, sum(units), sum(sales) from sales_a001
        where category_a = 1 AND category_b in ('001', '010', '018', '019', '024')
        and product in ('00000000000147', '00000000000900', '00000000000140', '00000000009999')
        group by category_a, category_b, product
UNION ALL select category_a, category_b, product, sum(units), sum(sales) from sales_a002
        where category_a = 2 AND 
        ..... repeat for all values of category_a
```

This combines many levels of bad design, but it runs in less than 20ms without the extra index.

---

I also tried clickhouse.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales2( 
    category_a  Int16           NOT NULL CODEC(Delta,ZSTD(9)),    -- sequential integer values from 0 - 10000
    category_b  FixedString(3)  NOT NULL CODEC(ZSTD(9)),  -- 3-digit ids (all numeric, padded with zeros)
    product     FixedString(14)     NOT NULL CODEC(ZSTD(9)), -- essentially random 14 character identifiers
    location_id FixedString(5)     NOT NULL CODEC(ZSTD(9)),  -- location id, 5-digit number (left padded with zeros)
    units       Int32           NOT NULL CODEC(ZSTD(9)),         -- value of interest
    sales       Float32         NOT NULL CODEC(ZSTD(9))       -- second value of interest
)   ENGINE=MergeTree -- eliminates duplicates with same (topic,ts) which should not occur
    PARTITION BY (category_a)
    ORDER BY (category_a,category_b,product)
    PRIMARY KEY (category_a,category_b,product)
    SETTINGS index_granularity=256;
```

I \copy data from postgres and load it. Compression ratio is about 6:1 which is not ideal due to text columns (storing numbers as ints would give a better result). The whole table and index takes about 340MB, versus 4.3GB for postgres: thanks to compression it's like having 12 times more RAM for disk cache.

The query in the question takes 20-70ms, depending on index granularity setting.

Switching the row storage order and primary key to (category_a,product,category_b) seems to make it faster, because product is more selective.

It could probably be optimized further, but this is only a 10-minute test.

Answer (score 0):

For the index to be used, you should have `product` as the first column in your primary key. For the third index column to be used effectively with an `IN` condition, all previous index columns would have to be compared with `=`, not with `IN`.